# Not initialized in user control?

Tags: c#, winforms, nhibernate, castle-activerecord

Any ideas as to why AR isn't being properly initialized when being used inside a user control? My initialization is properly being executed AFAIK because my parent form is successfully able to query. However, when I try querying within my user controls I get `Warning 1   An ActiveRecord class (Binder) was used but the framework seems not properly initialized. Did you forget about ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize() ?       0   0`. Which stops me from dragging my user control onto the form. If it helps, I initialize AR in Program.Main().

Here is the stacktrace:

```
at Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordBase.EnsureInitialized(Type type)
at Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordBase.FindAll(Type targetType, DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria, Order[] orders)
at Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordBase.FindAll(Type targetType)
at Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordBase`1.FindAll()
at TxLocates.BinderTabReferenceControl.BinderTabReferenceControl_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\dev\TxLocates\src\TxLocates\BinderTabReferenceControl.cs:line 56
at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.OnCreateControl()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.Add(Control value)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ControlCollection.Add(Control value)
at System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner.DesignerControlCollection.Add(Control c)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Visual Studio designer executes OnLoad for your user control, but doesn't run Program.Main(). Therefore ActiveRecord isn't initialized in the context of the designer.

Workarounds: use the [DesignMode property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode.aspx) to detect design mode to avoid executing ActiveRecord-related code, or try calling ActiveRecord from a different event.

Comment: Makes total sense. Thanks, Mauricio.